# Slow first query after update

Tags: solr

I have a 9Gb index and when I update the index (with delta-import or via xml), the first query is always very slow.

I have FastLRUCache and a newSearcher query configured (it's launched according to the log), but still have slowness in the first query.

How can I debug the source of this slowness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the newSearcher query not have a the facet field that was in the application query, so Solr have to do the query always.

The solution was to add this facet.field to the newSearcher in solrconfig.xml